# Getting a route from an object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a notifications panel where users can see notifications like:

'The client XXX paid his due'

'The product XXX is out of stock'

I need to make the notification clickable so they can click 'The client XXX paid his due' and they are taken to the XXX client show view.

In the notification I have the model class and the id.

Is there some way to generate the route for that model?

I have followed a name convention for the controllers (`ModelNameController`) and I think that I could generate a string like 'ModelController@show'.

Is there some way to get the route from 'ModelController@show'?

Comment: In laravel you just could use an anchor tag and set the href to your desired route.

Answer (score 0):

You would do that like this

**On Page**

```
<a href="/somePage"></a>
```

**In your routes**

```
Route::get('/somePage', 'PagesController@handle');
```

*Where your routes file changes depending on your version on laravel*

and the in the controller you put the code in you want i.e. the view you want to return etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the clickable url like `xurl($className.'/'.$id)`, 
add a route like

```
Route::get('{className}/{id}', function($className, $id) {
  return call_user_func_array($className.'::handle', [$id]);
}
```

Then in you controller's handle method get the item by id and render blade